# Extract single value from sqlite3 database

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I have a database with regression model intercepts, coefficients. I would like to extract the coefficients and convert them into a numpy array.

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT * FROM model_coeffs WHERE desc = 'L1 penalty model'""")
cursor.fetchall()
```

The output is shown below:

```
[(3, 'L1 penalty model', 'Intercept', '[0.]'),
 (3,
  'L1 penalty model',
  "['mean radius' 'mean texture' 'mean perimeter' 'mean area'\n 'mean smoothness' 'mean compactness' 'mean concavity'\n 'mean concave points' 'mean symmetry' 'mean fractal dimension'\n 'radius error' 'texture error' 'perimeter error' 'area error'\n 'smoothness error' 'compactness error' 'concavity error'\n 'concave points error' 'symmetry error' 'fractal dimension error'\n 'worst radius' 'worst texture' 'worst perimeter' 'worst area'\n 'worst smoothness' 'worst compactness' 'worst concavity'\n 'worst concave points' 'worst symmetry' 'worst fractal dimension']",
  '[[ 5.80829151e+00  1.47482359e-02 -4.59988460e-01 -9.43196068e-05\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00\n   6.72375188e-01 -5.25653647e-02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00 -2.04390704e-01 -1.03770307e-01 -2.79521678e-02\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.37746363e+00  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]')]
```

In this case, the coefficients are stored as a string. I would like to extract using Sqlite and convert them into an array so they look like such:

```
[[ 5.80829151e+00  1.47482359e-02 -4.59988460e-01 -9.43196068e-05
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   6.72375188e-01 -5.25653647e-02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00 -2.04390704e-01 -1.03770307e-01 -2.79521678e-02
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 -2.37746363e+00  0.00000000e+00
   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
```

I tried using `cursor.fetchone()`, but it only works for the first row (i.e extracting the value of the intercept). Whats a sql/pythonic way to retrieve the coefficients directly from the second row containing the coefficients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the sql will always return 2 rows, then do `fetchone()` twice, (this discarding the first row).

If the sql will return mulitple sets, do a `fetchall()`, iterate over the results, and discard (ignore) the even numbered rows